# How can I create a TrueCrypt volume container that's the exact size of all the files I want to store in it?

Tags: truecrypt

I have a folder containing static documents that I want to store inside a TrueCrypt (TC) volume.  I say static because these files will never change and I will never be adding additional files to the volume.  Here are the details of folder according to properties:

Size: 2.07 GB (2,229,324,081 bytes)
Size on disk: 2.08 GB (2,239,430,656 bytes)

Using number from size on disk and dividing by 1024, you get 2186944.  Therefore, I create my TC volume at 2186944 KB.  However, when I go to copy the folder into my TC volume, Windows tells me it needs an additional 32 MB to copy the files.

How can I properly calculate the exact file size for a brand new TC volume so that my files fit into it with 0 bytes of remaining space?

Comment: It's 2013 and we have already started to measure disk sizes in terabytes. I'd just add additional 100 MB, my time is to precious to spend it on fitting files with byte precision :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the filesystem metadata. Try adding an extra 1-2% of free space. Therefore if you have 2,239,430,656 bytes that would be +22,394,307 (21M) to +44,788,613 (42M). Just in case, it's always better to add the 2%.